# System.StackOverflowException, when get set Properties are used

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, devexpress

i have void method and i'm calling it on Account then this error occurs

```
Error: System.StackOverflowException on " da.Fill(dt) ".
```

what should i do? or how can i call GroupedAccount() in another way?

```
string fAccount;
[Key]
[Size(150)]
public string Account
{
    get { GroupedAccount(); return fAccount; }
    set { SetPropertyValue<string>(nameof(Account), ref fAccount, value); }
}
private void GroupedAccount()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Connection");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Traders", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
    conn.Open();
        var groupedData = from b in dt.AsEnumerable()
                          group b by b.Field<string>("Account Name") into g
                          select new
                          {
                              fAccounts = g.Key,
                          };

        foreach (var r in groupedData)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.TradersAccount (Account) VALUES (@Account)", conn);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account", r.fAccounts);
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: You need a private backing field for `Account`. If you set `Account` it calls the setter of `Account` which calls the setter of `Account`.....

Comment: You should not do a heavy loading logic inside a property's getter. Initialize your class (is it a viewmodel ?) via an Init method or whatever, and when your data is loaded, then notify your UI that the Account property has changed. I'm guessing you have some kind of "RaisePropertyChanged" method available somewhere

Comment: it looks like you're implementing some kind of lazy loading; the `GroupedAccount` method doesn't *actually* look like it calls back re-entrantly, so I don't *think* this should be recursive (is this the actual code? did you miss a line where `GroupedAccount()` touches `Account`?) - but it also isn't obvious why you call that method inside `Account` *at all*. I suspect the best idea here is just: *don't do this*; have the property be cheap and obvious, with a *callable method* for the other bits

Comment: i want to run groupedAccount automatically when my XAF project runs but it doesn't. so i decide to to such kind things i know its wrong. but how can i call another way?

Comment: it isn't full version of my code